# New Line Command (\n) Not Working With Firebase Firestore Database Strings

Tags: swift, string, firebase, newline, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making an app with Swift and I'm using Firebase Firestore. Firestore is a database that has some strings that I put into a `UILabel`. With some of my strings, I am using the new line command (or `\n)`. So some of my strings look like this:

```
"This is line one\nThis is line two\nThis is line three"
```

But, whenever that string is retrieved, it's addetoto the `UILabel` and appears like this...

**This is line one\nThis is line two\nThis is line three**

...when it should be like this...

**This is line one**

**This is line two**

**This is line three**

I'm assuming that `\n` does not work with strings coming from a database? I've tried double escaping with `\\n`. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Here is the code that I am using...

```
    database.collection("songs").whereField("storyTitle", isEqualTo: "This is the story header").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        
        for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
            self.storyBodyLabel.text = (document.data()["storyBody"] as? String)!
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried double escaping it (eg. `\\n`)?

Comment: @l'L'l Yes, I have.

Comment: As Doug answered: the Firebase Database doesn't modify your strings in any way. If you store a `\n`, it will be there when you read it back. But if that doesn't translate into a newline in your `UILabel` that problem is likely later in the code. It will be a lot easier to help if you [create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which includes **code** that 1) saves the string, 2) loads the string, 3) sets the string to a `UILabel`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ok. Just updated my question. The string is already in the database, so there is no saving process.

Comment: We'll need to know what the code is actually reading., so please update your question with the JSON from the database. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am using Firebase Firestore. I do not see an Export JSON like in Firebase Database.

Comment: Ah, good point. :-) A screenshot of the console with the document in question would also do in that case.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ok. There ya go! It's been updated.

Comment: Yeah, you are putting literal characters "\n" in there.  It doesn't work like that - see my answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got it. I simply just replaced the character "\n" from the string that I was receiving with the newline command.

```
label.text = stringRecived.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\n")
```

Because I manually typed out my string and gave Firebase a string like
`"Line one\nline two\nline three"` I am replacing "\n" with "\n" But if you give Firebase a string like

```
"Line one
Line two
Line three"
```

Firebase replaces those returns with `"\\n"` therfore making the code

```
label.text = stringRecived.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n")
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Are you sure you are replacing \n? Firebase converts \n into \\n so you need to convert back with stringRecived.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n")

Comment: Rufat Mirza has the right answer for this issue!, thanks for your comment

Comment: Thank you for answer! Now the command is stringRecived.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\\n'), '\n')

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS whitespace property for \n, it works for me.

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

Comment: yes it does work. Also if we use tilde `` it works awesome.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution: Add this to your string and you are done (for Java users):**

> .replace("\\n", "\n")

**Example:**

```
    if (dataSnapshot.exists())
    {
    ArrayList<String> userlogs2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    userlogs2.add(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().replace("\\n", "\n"));
    
    Iterator<String> it2 = userlogs2.iterator();
    

    while (it2.hasNext()) {
    
    appendColoredText(userlogsmessages2, it2.next() + "\n", Color.BLACK);
    
    appendUnderlinedText(userlogsmessages2,"____________" + "\n\n", Color.parseColor("#DB808080"));
    
                                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firestore doesn't support any escape sequences within string values.  If you write "\n" in a string, you're going to get exactly that back when you read it.  If you need to store something special, you may want to encode and decode that yourself.

Comment: Do you mean "Firebase Realtime Database doesn't support newline characters [and some other characters]"? Database storage and string literals are separate issues.

Comment: No, you can put whatever characters you want in Firestore.  I even put emoji in there recently.  You just can't expect Firestore to understand any sort of character escape sequences that might have meaning in programming languages. https://twitter.com/CodingDoug/status/961302822997213184

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm sorry. I'm fairly new to coding. How would I do this?

Comment: That sounds like a different question to ask here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ok. I'll look and see if anyone else has asked. I'm sure they have. Thanks for your help! 

Comment: @DougStevenson 'If you write "\n" in a string, ...' It looks like you meant a string generated from a string literal containing `\n` (i.e. a string containing a newline character, generated from a literal). But now I think you meant a string consisting of the characters `\` and `n` (which you'd get from the string literal `"\\n"`). And you're not saying that Firebase doesn't accept strings generated from string literals containing `\n`, you're just saying that Firebase doesn't do any escaping itself. Is this what you meant? Just trying to clarify things.

Comment: Firestore will take the string data exactly as it appears in the string *at runtime*, as passed to the API.  At compile time, there may be a \n visible to the developer in source code, but that may have special meaning to the  compiler (encoded newline), and that's not at all visible to Firestore.  It'll just see the newline at runtime.  If the developer attempts to use \\n to effectively pass the characters \n to Firestore, it will take those characters literally and do no other transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Tried all of the answers suggested but none worked for me.  In the end, I fixed it by using `"/n"` in the Firestore record and, in the Swift client, the following:

```
label.text = stringReceived.replacingOccurrences(of: "/n", with: "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

For me firebase turned all \n to \\\\n , so I just reversed that change with :

```
theString.replaceAll( "\\\\n", "\n" );
```

Just posting cause I wasted some time calculating the right number of '\'

Answer (score 0):

I found I could get newlines into a firestore field by using the String.fromCharCode() function. Firestore seems to need special characters in strings to be the actual character ASCII values and does not reinterpret escape characters.

i.e.

"First Line " + String.fromCharCode(13) + "second line"

Answer (score 0):

**100% Working**

```
DB.collection(Global.DB_COLLECTION_PATH).document(NEWS_ID).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener< DocumentSnapshot >() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task< DocumentSnapshot > task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            body1 = task.getResult().getString("newsBody").replace("\n", "\n");
            nBody.setText(body1);
        }
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.e("DB FAILED", e.getMessage());
    }
});
```

*I hope it's work for you*

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when you add a string with \n to the JSON export and then upload the JSON to the Realtime Database, it acts as a newline. But if you edit that from the firebase console, it gives you back the string with \n and not a newline.

Answer (score -1):

Firestore add this type----Line one\nline two\nline three

get Sting, replace and show with TextView

String sura=modellist.get(position).getSura().replace( "\n", "\n");

Working..