# Firebase Firestore new line command

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to utilize a new line command to create a new line in text. It appears from this issue that this is not possible: [New Line Command (\n) Not Working With Firebase Firestore Database Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48755746/new-line-command-n-not-working-with-firebase-firestore-database-strings)

Is this still the case? Assuming so, does Flutter offer any methods with similar functionality to the following that would allow me to work around this?

```
label.text = stringRecived.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\n")
```

*More context: 
Here is a picture of my Firestore string where I entered the data. 
[image: Firestore string with line break]

I then use a future builder to call this from Firestore and then pass the string (in this case comment) into another widget.

```
return new SocialFeedWidget(
  filter: false,
  articleID: document['article'],
  article_header: document['article_title'],
  userName: document['author'],
  spectrumValue: document['spectrum_value'].toDouble(),
  comment: document['comment'],
  fullName: document['firstName'] + " " + document['lastName'],
  user_id: document['user_id'],
  postID: document.documentID,
  posterID: userID,
  );
}).toList(),
```

In the new widget, I pass it in as a string an feed it via a Text widget as follows:

```
new Text(
  comment,
  style: new TextStyle(
    color: Color.fromRGBO(74, 74, 74, 1.0),
    fontSize: 13.0,
  ),
),
```

When it appears, it still has the \n within the string. 
[image: From the console]

Comment: There is nothing special about storing `\n` in a string, you should get back exactly what you stored. But if  you note the [first comment to the answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48755746/new-line-command-n-not-working-with-firebase-firestore-database-strings#comment85108110_48874269), you'll see that they store `\\n` instead of `\n`.

Comment: @Frank Thank you for clarification. It looks like there is no way of bypassing this in Firestore and that I will have to handle in flutter. Is there any other way around this? Any idea how I can replace occurrences of "\n" in flutter?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to bypass. What is the problem you're having when you store strings that contain a `\n` sequence?

Comment: @Frank When I store the sequence: `The Cat jumped \n over the fence` it displays as "The Cat jumped \n over the fence" when in Flutter UI.

Comment: And when you don't get that from Firestore, but hard-code the string, do you have the same problem?

Comment: @Frank No, if I hard code that within the Flutter Text Widget like `new Text("The cat jumped \n over the fence");` the line will properly break.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting. I'm not aware of Firestore making any changes to the strings you store in it. The `\n` should really just be treated as an other character. Can you set up a minimal snippet of code that I can run to reproduce this?

Comment: @Frank Thanks for your help. I added more context above.

Comment: I have a feeling that you have stored the literal two-character string `\n` in your document. This is different from storing a single-character newline in there. While the latter is escaped in most programming languages as the character sequence `\n`, it is actually stored as a single character. That would mean that you have to convert back the two-character `\n` to a single newline character, which you can do in most programming languages by replacing `"\\n"` with `"\n"`.

Answer (score 52):

In most programming languages if you include `\n` in a string, it interprets the two characters as a (escape) sequence and it actually stores a single non-printable character with ASCII code 10.

If you literally type `\n` into a document in the Firestore console however, it stores that exact literal value in the string. So that's two characters `\` and `n`.

These two are not the same. In fact, if you'd want to enter the two-character sequence in a string in most programming languages you'd end up with `"\\n"`. That's two backslashes: the first to start an escape sequence, the second to indicate it's a literal `\`, and then a literal `n`.

So if you've stored the literal two-characters `\n` in a string and you want to display it as a newline in your Flutter app, you need to decode the string back into a single line break character. This is luckily quite simple with:

```
yourString.replaceAll("\\n", "\n");
```

For example, this is what I just tested in an app. My document in the Firestore console shows:

[image: Literal two-character \n sequence in a document in the Firestore console]

And then my code:

```
var doc = await Firestore.instance.collection("weather").document("sf").get();
var weather = doc.data["condition"]
print(weather);
print(weather.replaceAll("\\n", "\n"));
```

That first `print` statement, prints:

> `Sunny\nI think`

While the second prints:

> `Sunny`

> `I think`

---

Fun fact: when I run this code in Flutter:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("weather").document("test").setData({ 'condition': "nice\nand\nsunny" });
```

It shows up like this in the Firestore console:

[image: Unprintable newlines show as space in Firestore console]

So it looks like the unprintable `\n` in the string shows up as a space in the console. I haven't found a way yet to enter a newline into a string in the Firestore console. The API retrieves the line breaks correctly though, so this only affects the Firebase console.

Comment: Thanks @frank appreciate the help. Interesting to see that about pushing data to firestore too

Answer (score 13):

Old thread I know, but for anyone that stumbles here...

If you pass `\n` to Firestore in a block of text you will indeed not see it if you got look for it in the Firebase console.  It is still there though.  All you need to do in order to get the new line to work is apply `white-space: pre-wrap` css to the element where the text is being rendered.

Comment: i think OP is using flutter and not html/css per-se

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following in your html style or css:

```
white-space: pre-line;
line-break: anywhere;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the **problem** so what solved my problem is that **line of code** that I used simply. **itemDescription.replaceAll("\n", "\n")** here in this line **itemDescription** is my variable name which has multiple lines of text. so when I used this specific line of code it gave me **required result** which I was searching for.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this issue by wrapping the element with a parent with style props `white-space: pre-line`. Followed by the `replaceAll()` method:

```
<div style={{whiteSpace: 'pre-line'}}>
    {(content).replaceAll(`<br />`, `\n`)}
</div>
```