# New line with react-markdown

Tags: reactjs, firebase, markdown

I am trying to pull the markdown string from firebase database then using react-markdown to render it into Component. But the markdown string doesn't show correctly. I think the problem is due to start with new line.

I tried to declare the variable I put markdown in there. it works. 
[markdown string which is created in Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S29sz.png)

But the markdown string which is pulled from firebase database. it doesn't show correctly.
[markdown string which is pulled from firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InnTf.png)

Here is my code

```
export default function BlogTemplate() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  useFirestoreConnect([
    {
      collection: "communications",
      doc: id
    }
  ]);
  const post = useSelector(
    state =>
      state.firestore.data.communications &&
      state.firestore.data.communications[id]
  );

  if (post) {
    const input =
      "# This is a header\n\nAnd this is a paragraph \n\n # This is header again"; // this is a markdown string created in Component
    const postContent = post.content; // This is the markdown string pulled from firebase database
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Container>
          <Content className="pt-5 pb-5">
            <ReactMarkdown source={input} />
            <ReactMarkdown source={postContent} />
          </Content>
        </Container>
      </Layout>
    );
  } else {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }
}
```

Comment: You may want to replace `\n\n` to what you want using js feature directly.

Comment: @keikai `\n\n` still works in `input variable`. So I dont think that is the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue.  Markdown sourced from a .md file or hard-coded in a variable is rendered properly.  I am also using Firestore, and any markdown pulled from there does not render properly.  Carriage returns and headers are ignored.  Do you find a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Firestore new line command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827739/firebase-firestore-new-line-command)

Answer (score 6):

first create css class forexample

```
.foo {white-space: 'pre-wrap';}
```

then add classname to markdown component

```
<ReactMarkdown source={input} className="foo" />
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you need to add 2 empty spaces before \n like this:
"This is a header  \n  \nAnd this is a paragraph".

Let me know if that works for you.

More info here:
https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown/issues/273

Comment: This creates a new Paragraph, not a new line like `<br/>` tag does. What if you want to add a new line inside of a paragraph?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get this behavior? @AntoniSilvestrovič

Comment: @DeveloperRyan Honestly, I think I just ignored this problem at that time xD But right now I'd just use remark/rehype and add support for the `<br/>` tag, it would be the easiest approach.

Answer (score 2):

If pre-wrap is applied to the entire markdown, the display will be weird in other parts, so I solved it like this.

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { FC, ReactNode } from 'react';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';

type Props = {
  className?: string;
  children?: ReactNode;
  markdown: string;
};

const SC = {
  P: styled('p')(({ theme }) => ({
    whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap',
  })),
};

const MarkDownView: FC<Props> = React.memo(function MarkdownView({ className, markdown }) {
  return (
    <ReactMarkdown
      className={className}
      remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]}
      components={{
        p({ className, children, ...props }) {
          return <SC.P className={className}>{children}</SC.P>;
        },
      }}
    >
      {markdown}
    </ReactMarkdown>
  );
});

export default MarkDownView;
```

Target is Paragraphs tag

Answer (score 1):

Hope help someone with this, when you retreive a string from firebase, I don't know why it adds an extra "/" to the new lines.
Eg: "\n" => "\n".
So you need to replace it like this:

```
const parseToMarkDown = (str: string): string => {
    return str.replace(/\\n/g, "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore stores the string as a plain test, some extra space, a new line and other characters are somehow removed by firestore.

I fixed this by saving my content encoded as base64 string

```
 const encoded = Buffer.from(content).toString("base64") // on node nevironment
```

and then decode it back when I want to use it

```
 const decoded = Buffer.from(encoded,"base64").toString("utf8") // on node environment
```

If you want to do encoding on browser, you will need to use other technics like "TextEncoder"

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:** One way is to simply replace the new lines with HTML `<br/>` should solve the problem.

Use **ReactMarkdown** with [**rehype-raw**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rehype-raw) plugin.

```
text.replace(/\\n/gi, "\n").replace(/\n/gi, "<br/>");
```

**e.g:**

```
import rehypeRaw from "rehype-raw";
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm";


const SomeComponent = () => {

 const text = "Foo\nBar\nBaz";

 return (
  <ReactMarkdown
     children={text}
     remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]}
     rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]}
   />
 )
}
```

```
// Output 

Foo
<br/>
Bar
<br/>
Baz
```