# Firebase & Flutter : Line breaks?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, text

For the 'blog' part of a site, I need to read some data stored on Firebase, but the problem is, I can't figure out how to insert line breaks, or make some of the text bold when the text is from a Firebase document ... line breaks are what matters most. I tried: '\ n', "< br >", it doesn't work, no surprise! I really have no idea. Someone?

That's my data :

[image]

This is my code :

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: _posts.doc('myDocument').get(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    return Text(
      '${data['Content']}',
      // some design stuff
    );
  }
),
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: "it doesn't work" is really hard to help with. Please show the code that you wrote, and explain what doesn't work about it.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, I updated my post.

Comment: The Firebase console doesn't show newlines, so I think you have a literal `\` follow by an `n` in your text. See my answer here on the difference and how to convert the `\\n` to an actual newline character: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827739/firebase-firestore-new-line-command

Comment: Thank you for your time, your answer on the other question is really helping !! :)