# Firestore value field omits spaces

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm reading data from a "besede" field from a Firestore document. The field is created by Cloud Vision. There are normal spaces between words displayed in the console. However, if I click edit field the value  shown is without spaces. This happens in cases where the words (which are read by Cloud Vision) are not in the same lines. For example:

Jogurt
Mu Athenticos

is displayed in the console as:
Jogurt Mu Athenticos

But the in field value is:
JogurtMu Athenticos

Here is how I am reading the code:

```
fs.collection('besedila').where(ft.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', props.location.state.docID).onSnapshot((doc)=>{
      doc.forEach(snap=>{
      console.log(snap.data()['besede'][0]);
      setBesede(snap.data()['besede'][0])       
    })  
    })
  })
```

The code also omits the space.
How could I have the space between as it is shown in the Firestore console?

Screenshots of Firestore console:
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can replace multiple spaces or new lines with single space while adding data to Firestore maybe. `replace(/\s+/g, " ")`

Comment: While it's possible that the console displays a certain Unicode character differently, the API will not in any way alter what you read/write. Can you copy/paste the top value from your console (so where it has the space) and paste it here?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen If I try to copy it from Firestore console, it immediately displays the value filed (second screenshot). I can only copy it from there (where it has no space).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've just noticed that in logs of firebase functions that the text by cloud vision is logged so: 'JOGURT\nMU ATHENTIKOS\n'

Comment: Good, that explains   Those are line breaks, which the Firestore console will indeed display as a space - and may not allow you to enter. But the API call really *does* return the text with the line break in there. Also see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827739/firebase-firestore-new-line-command