# Detect line breaks (\n) while reading from a database (Javascript, HTML, firebase)

Tags: javascript, html, string, firebase, line-breaks

I'm trying to use a string retrieved from firebase firestore and display it on my HTML page with line breaks.

In the store, I have a string that looks like this

row1\nrow2\nrow3

When I retrieve it and try to add it to my page the \n's do not register as line breaks. I am using pre-wrap and using a test-string works fine.

```
let text = getString(); //retrieves a string from firebase
document.getElementById('textBox').textContent = text;
```

Shows this on my page:

> row1\nrow2\nrow3

The following test code:

```
let text = 'row1\nrow2\nrow3';
document.getElementById('textBox').textContent = text;
```

Shows the following on the page:

> row1
>
> row2
>
> row3

So it seems like the \n's in the string retrieved from the database are not read the same way as the \n's that are put inside the string defined directly in the Javascript code. Any idea why? And what can I do to make it read the line breaks?

Comment: If your string comes with '\\n', why would not you just do a replace on '\\n' to be '\n'. Note `\\` usage, single and double.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what @user14063792468 said in their comment, it appears your newline characters have been escaped (i.e., converts `\n` to `\\n`) when a string is stored, so I'd try to replace any instances of `\\n` with `\n` (single backslash) and see if that works.

Here's an example of how this might look before and after the replacement:

```js
let string = 'Newline characters\\nare in this\\nstring\\nfor sure';  // note the double slashes

document.getElementById('before').textContent = string;
let text = string.replace(/\\n/g, "\n");
document.getElementById('after').textContent = text;
```

```html
<pre id="before"></pre>
<pre id="after"></pre>
```

Comment: *firebaser here* While replacing the double "\\" is the solution here (upvoted), Firebase does nothing to the data that is stored in it. If the newline characters are escaped in the stored data, that happened before it reached the database, typically by some code that mishandles (or fails to handle) escape sequences. --- Edit: found an explanation I gave a while ago heere: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53858404 and likely that happened here too: `\n` was entered in an area that doesn't interpret it as a newline character.