# <p> tag, allowing new line/row from input

Tags: html, firebase

Im just building a blog of mine and was wondering how i can make sure new rows from my input in textarea actually renders as new rows.

Lets say my input is:

```
Im Freddy.

Im 27 years old.
```

But it renders
`Im Freddy. Im 27 years old`

How can i make sure it renders with a new row? Im storing all my posts on firebase.
Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "*But it renders...*" - how does it render? Where's your code to handle that?

Comment: I mean if you wanna see the entire component here it is: https://wtools.io/paste-code/bEdo

Comment: No, relevant "*[mcve]*" code must be in the question, in order to guard against link-rot and questions ultimately becoming useless to future visitors. Please check the "*[ask]*" guidelines, as well as the "*[mcve]*".

Comment: The issue is that Firebase doesn't store *line breaks* (that you need)which is what the issue is. There are a BUNCH of [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5Dstore+line+breaks) here on SO. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827739/firebase-firestore-new-line-command).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make sure you are using the `<p>` tag as block level element. I think in your css `<p>` tag has `display: inline-block;` or to parent.

Comment: Thanks, im just using a normal <p> tag inside a `Box` element from `Chakra UI`...

Not sure how i can solve this

Comment: Can you please share codepen?

Comment: hi! 

https://wtools.io/paste-code/bEdo

Comment: Use text component instead simple html markup. See below link for details.

https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/text/usage

Comment: Thanks, i already tried with Text component before, doesn't help my case unfortunetly. :/