# How to keep text formatting while displaying data from Firestore "Flutter"

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am displaying data in my application from Firebase Firestore, but when displaying texts, they do not keep the same formatting. For example, if there is a blank line between the text, it is deleted while displaying it in the application. I only want to keep the empty lines while displaying them in the application.

i use flutter.

I manually enter the data into Firestore and then display it in the application as follows:

model file:

```
class Post {
  final String title;
  final String image;
  final String des;

  const Post({
    required this.title,
    required this.image,
    required this.des,
  });

  Post.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      : this(
          title: json['title']! as String,
          image: json['image']! as String,
          des: json['des']! as String,
        );
  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {
        'title': title,
        'image': image,
        'des': des,
      };
}
```

The second file: ( I display it here through ListView.Builder ):

```
 final queryPost =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('thedata').withConverter<Post>(
            fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Post.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
            toFirestore: (user, _) => user.toJson(),
          );
```

Comment: Give us more information please. How is the data formatted? How are you loading it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice this and added more details now

Comment: Can you have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53858404/18265570)?

Answer (score 0):

Your test should contain `\n` for empty lines when you set your data:

> Example Example Example Example Example Example \n Example2 Example2

now where you get and parse it inside your flutter app, it will be same as I did wrote, but when when you try `print()` with it, it will be two lines.

> Example Example Example Example Example Example

> Example2 Example2

Comment: I tried this method, but it does not work with data coming from FireStore. \n is printed as it is, and no blank line is added

Answer (score 0):

Then you can go for Mongo DB Cloud Database which can store formatted text and returns formatted text as well

**Mongo Db Data Api could work almost similar to Cloud Firestore by simply converting an existing database/collection as an api end point**

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/api/data-api/