# String with line breaks "\n" used for UILabel inside UITableViewCell not breaking

Tags: firebase, newline

Can't get the String to break into lines. I'm passing the data from MainViewController to be displayed in a single row table. I've tried passing the object product with a class of Product therefore getting the product description as product.description. I've also tried just passing the String instead but either way I get the result shown in the images. The descriptions comes from a Firestore database stored as for example: string Available In Black And White\nOne Piece Swimsuit\nScoop Neck\nCheeky Coverage\nStrappy Detail At Back\n90% Nylon 10% Spandex\nFinal Sale

I've tried several ways:

```
var product: Product?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "description", for: indexPath) as! ProductDescriptionTableViewCell
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = product?.description
    return cell
}
```

or loading the description in viewDidLoad()

```
var product: Product?
var productDescription = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    productDescription = product!.description
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "description", for: indexPath) as! ProductDescriptionTableViewCell
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = productDescription
    return cell
}
```

I still can't get the desired outcome of the String breaking using "\n". I tested it and it works adding the text directly using:

```
cell.descriptionLabel.text = "Available In Black And White\nOne Piece Swimsuit\nScoop Neck\nCheeky Coverage\nStrappy Detail At Back\n90% Nylon 10% Spandex\nFinal Sale"
```

so I know that the cell's height and the label's number of lines work.

[image]

Comment: How did those `\n` get in the string you stored in Firebase? `\n` only works when typed in literally to a string and then compiled. The \ and `n` characters don't mean anything if not compiled at build time.

Comment: I added the description including the \n to Firebase. How would you go about adding those line breaks?

Comment: How did you add them? You need to enter actual newline characters, not a \ followed by an `n`.

Comment: How do you do that in firebase?

Comment: Got the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48874269/2185588. I'm adding the description as I did before and on build time break the lines with .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n")

Comment: It would be better if you don’t put \ and n in Firebase to begin with. Then you don’t need to process the data every time it is loaded.

Comment: I agree but Firebase does not support line breaks. The text is going to read as a single line regardless.