# Can Cloud firestore database use multi lines?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I’m trying to make a notes app in a terminal but I don’t know if I can add multi-lines to be stored in the cloud firestore database.

Comment: Yes, line break characters can be stored in Firestore. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56681520/does-cloud-firestore-save-strings-with-newline-n-characters-multiline and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827739/firebase-firestore-new-line-command on some idiosyncrasies in how the Firebase *console* displays (or rather: doesn't display) line breaks.

Comment: Hi @Panda , have you checked my posted answer? Let me know if you have any questions and clarifications. Also, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Yes I have already seen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're using `python` to store data in Firestore. Yes, you can store multi-lines in Firestore by having `\n` in each string that you'll be storing. e.g:

```
string = 'Line1\nLine2\nLine3'
print(string)
# Line1
# Line2
# Line3
```

Storing it in the Firestore:

```
string = 'Line1\nLine2\nLine3'

data = {
    u'string': string,
}

db.collection(u'<collection-name>').document(u'<document-name>').set(data)
```

For more information, you may check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document).