# text added to firebase console can't use interpolation

Tags: flutter, firebase-console

If I add text with '\n' to firebase String field from FirebaseConsole it would be simplified and remove line interpolation.

Try paste text with line interpolation to description String field in firebaseConsole (for ex. text have line breaks). After deserealise models it simplified to one line text.

Comment: as descirbed here, that console it is just UI and not designed for this purposes, the only way to do so is use admin web site, or CLI scripts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73973741/12041701