# How can I add a line return into json?

Tags: json

I have a seemingly simply question.  How do I insert a line break within a json fetched data.  This json is being passed from a remote firebase server.

Here is my json

```
    [ {
  "body" : "Hello, my name is __________________ (state your name). \nI wish this text to be on a new line",
  "hideOrShow" : true,
  "icon" : "./assets/imgs/test.svg",
  "title" : "Test"
} ]
```

Yet my code keep printing the body as one line of text.  No new line is added.

What am I doing wrong?

Updated: I am using ionic 5 and printing the json like so:

```
        <ion-item class="ion-text-wrap text-import">
      {{sanitizeAndUnescapeHtml(s.body)}}
    </ion-item>
```

(from my .ts file:

```
    sanitizeAndUnescapeHtml(body: string): string {
  const sanitized = this.domSanitzer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, body);
  // console.log('s', sanitized);
  const parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(sanitized, 'text/html');
  // console.log('p', parsed.textContent);
  return parsed.documentElement.textContent;
}
```

Comment: How are you printing the json object.

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48755746/new-line-command-n-not-working-with-firebase-firestore-database-strings

Comment: If you're printing it in HTML you should use the `pre` node to preserve text formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is special since there are two data types.
So a little difficult to add \n on the types by program.
Use this json formatter.

```
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.  The solution was to escape the HTML and then change this code line:

```
  <div style="overflow-y: auto;" [innerHTML]="sanitizeAndUnescapeHtml(e.body)"></div>
```