# How does one use the FirestoreDataConverter with update?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use the `FirestoreDataConverter` to transform objects to firestore data but it seems that the converter only works for the `addDoc` and `setDoc` operations but when trying to use it with an `updateDoc` operation, it doesn't trigger the `toFirestore` function.

**Reproducible example**

```js
interface Post {
  author: string;
  content: string;
}

async function addAndUpdatePost() {
  const colRef = collection(firestore, 'posts')
    .withConverter(postConverter);
  const post: Post = { author: 'Author', content: 'Content'};
  const docRef = doc(colRef);
  await setDoc(docRef, post);                      // Triggers toFirestore function
  const addedPost = (await getDoc(docRef)).data(); // Triggers fromFirestore function
  if (!addedPost) return;
  await updateDoc(docRef, addedPost)               // Does NOT trigger toFirestore function
}

const postConverter: FirestoreDataConverter<Post> = {
  toFirestore(post: Post): DocumentData {
    console.log("Went through to-converter");
    return { ...post};
  },

  fromFirestore(docSnap: QueryDocumentSnapshot): Post {
    console.log("Went through from-converter")
    return docSnap.data() as Post;
  },
};
```

**Expected console output**

```
Went through to-converter
Went through from-converter
Went through to-converter
```

**Actual console output**

```
Went through to-converter
Went through from-converter
```

This happens specifically with `updateDoc`. If I use `setDoc` instead, it works as expected. Is `updateDoc` simply not supported? Doesn't seem like it's mentioned at all in the docs.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter

Comment: What's the point of using a converter with an interface here? Converters are meant to be used with classes by the way.

Comment: @vdegenne I don't see how converters would only be meant for classes as it is useful to transform objects regardless if they are class instances or not. For example, one use case for me is [handling unescaped newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48755746/new-line-command-n-not-working-with-firebase-firestore-database-strings).

Comment: @vdegenne I'm curious about your comment as I'm just learning about converters in Firestore. I often think classes are overkill and use interfaces instead. Is there a better way to get type safety with interfaces while not using converters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converter is designed to help convert the top level (`T`) data structure. In `set()`, the data type you passed to it is either `T` or `partial T`, that's why the converter takes effect.

On the other side, `update()` is used to update the fields, where the fields can sit inside the nested data structure in Document and are not necessary `partial T`. So it will not trigger converter.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Didn't know that `update()` could refer to nested fields. Thanks 

Comment: A workaround would be to use `await setDoc(docRef, dto, { merge: true });`. It will add it and merge if existing

Comment: @Foxhunt In my case I wanted to make sure that it wouldn't create a document if it referred to a non-existing document which is why I specifically looked for update instead of set. I used `setDoc` before and managed to introduce a bug that created a bunch of duplicate documents

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your code, you're using Firestore Web Version 9 that has the new syntax for setting and updating the data. You may refer [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js) for proper reference.

The behavior that you encountered is working as intended. The [`updateDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#updatedoc) function in Web Version 9 uses a new [`UpdateData`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#updatedata) type that does the type checking and supports Field Values.

Comment: This helped me a bit but what I was still missing was why the `UpdateData<T>` would be any different from the type `Partial<T>` used by `setDoc()`. But it was explained to me in the recent answer (`UpdateData<T>` can refer to nested fields so it might not be `Partial<T>`).