# Unable to split a string from Firebase Firestore into a list of strings using “\n” as separator

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I’m trying to split a string that I get from Firestore into a list of strings using “\n” as the separator character. Here’s my code:

```
db.collection("categories")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    String s = document.getData().get("palabras").toString();
                    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(s.split("\n"));
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

However, this doesn’t seem to be working. The words list is being populated with a single string that contains the entire original string from the database. Can anyone help me figure out what’s going wrong?

Comment: We don't have enough information to know what the problem is, because we can't see the string you're using. It might be the case that the string doesn't have any newlines in it at all.  Please edit the question to show enough information that anyone can use the reproduce the problem and observe the result.

Comment: TL:DR; For the [connected thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70607099), Firebase converts `\n` when it's uploaded to Firestore as `\\n`. However because ``\`` is also escaped as ``\\`` it only gets converted back to ``\`` and no further meaning is applied. So to handle your situation, execute your split using a literal ``\n`` using ``s.split("\\n")``.

Comment: For any future readers, if you want to comment with backslashes, you need to use two backticks on either side instead of just one. e.g. `<backtick><backtick><backslash><backtick><backtick>`